# Spring Boot Override Property in Service Class With TestPropertySource Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have a few properties in service class like below. I can fill them from application.properties file.

My application.properties file is like this and it's values same with application-test.properties file:

```
server.port=8282
short.url.domain=gnl.co
```

application.properties in src/main/resources, application-test.properties in src/test/resources.

My service class is like this:

```
@Service
public class ShortURLService {
    @Value("${short.url.domain}")
    private String shortUrlDomain;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String shortUrlPort;

    .....

}
```

I have a test class like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ShortURLService.class)
public class ShortURLServiceTest {


  @InjectMocks
  private ShortURLService shortURLService;


   @Test
    public void testShortenURL() {
        String shortUrl = shortURLService.shortenURL("http://ilkaygunel.com");
        assertTrue(shortUrl.contains("gnl.co/"));
    }

}
```

I checked that values from application-test.properties file comes to ShortURLServiceTest class but values in ShortURLService are null.

How can fill variables in service class with application-test.properties file?

Comment: how do you define ShortURLService in your test codes ?

Comment: With InjectMocks annotation. 
Like this:
    @InjectMocks
    ShortURLService shortURLService;

Answer (score 2):

Because `@InjectMocks` is the Mockito stuff and it does not know anything about Spring and so it does not understand what `@Value` is and will not inject values to it.

You have to use `@Autowired` to inject the actual `ShortURLService` bean from the spring context into the test.

So change to the following should solve your problem :

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ShortURLService.class)
public class ShortURLServiceTest {

   
   @Autowired
   private ShortURLService shortURLService;

    @Test
    public void testShortenURL() {
       
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Now, I can run tests with test properties.

Comment: good to hear. so consider to upvote or accept my answer please?